# How to create separate private folder for captured images?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to create a separate folder for captured images using the code and below code is working fine for creating separate folder and images also saved in that folder

My problem is captured images also appear in **gallery** and I don't want to show them in my **gallery**, Can someone help me please what will I do for my requirement

### code:

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);



  private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

 Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
 File compressedFile1 = Utilities.saveImage(this, bitmap);

}



public static File saveImage(Context context, Bitmap imgBitmap) {

        File mediaFile = null;
        try {
            //Bitmap imgBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File imageFolder = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    ".FOSImages");
            if (!imageFolder.isDirectory()) {
                imageFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            mediaFile = new File(imageFolder + File.separator + "fos_" +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
            imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            return mediaFile;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: Just place an empty file with the name `.nomedia` in that folder.

Comment: imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Comment: i think for this code images also appear in gallaery

Comment: actually using above code captured images are appearing in my gallery and separate folder too, I don't want to show them in gallery

Comment: `i think for this code images also appear in gallaery` Then why do you execute that code?

Comment: It looks as if you manage to create two image files. One is taken and saved by the used camera app. The other one by you in onActivityResult(). Why this construction?

Comment: You will then see only the pictures of the camera app in Gallery. Not those of yours in FOSImages folder if there is a `.nomedia` file.

Comment: can you please post proper code as per my requirement

Comment: Can you please react on the things i analized? And tell what you actually want?

Comment: my requirement is captured images have to store separate folder and those images should not show in my gallery

Comment: If you use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT you can let the camera app store the image directly in FOSimages. So no need to save again in onActivityResult(). No need to create two files as you do now.

Comment: if i not use  MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT image quality is loosing

Comment: with out using MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT my code is working perfectly but image quality is loosing

Comment: You should use EXTRA_OUTPUT of course. But not as you do it now.

Comment: ok but can please post some code as per my requirement

Comment: Google for EXTRA_OUTPUT and you find a thousand examples of how to do it right. And maybe the one of you where you do all wrong ;-).

Answer (score 0):

It's appearing in Gallery because you are using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, this returns a public path accessible by all apps. So one solution is to use a private external path `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), folderName)`, the files saved here will not be accessible by `MediaScanner` and therefore not visible in the Gallery, although they will be deleted when your app is deleted.